# Simple String Rewriting System in Python

Tags: python, replace, rewriting

I'm trying to create a script rewriting system so that after each iteration all A will change to B and all B will change to AB. The initial state is ABA so the first iteration should yield BABB but the code I have returns ABABAB. I'm really new to python as you can probably tell from my code below so if you could explain why what I'm doing is going so wrong that would be much appreciated as well

```
SRS = { 'a':'b', 'b':'ab'}
script = "aba"
for key in SRS:
    script = script.replace(key,SRS[key])
    print(script)
```

Comment: Since your loop is for key in SRS, it is looping through the SRS dictionary, not each character in the script.  That would make the loop run twice since you have two kay/value pairs in the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

In the first step, you replace all `a` with `b`:

```
"aba" -> "bbb"
```

and then replace `b` with `ab`:

```
"bbb" -> "ababab"
```

If you want to replace character by charater you have to loop over `script`:

```
SRS = { 'a':'b', 'b':'ab'}
script = "aba"
result = ""
for ch in script:
    result += SRS[ch]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're replacing a with b first...so you have "bbb" and then replacing b with ab, so you get "ababab"

here's the code you need:

```
SRS = { 'a':'b', 'b':'ab'}
script = "aba"
script_replaced = ""
for character in script:
    script_replaced += SRS[character]

print(script)
print(script_replaced)
```

Note that we loop over each character in the string and replace with a match in the dictionary

Comment: I think this answer is good and could be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having here is that the `script = script.replace(key,SRS[key])` is running over all the `script` variable, not character by character. If you run the replacement character by character then it can work:

```
SRS = { 'b':'ab', 'a':'b',}
script = "aba"
new_script = ''
for letter in script:    
    new_script += SRS[letter]
print(new_script)
```

Comment: I think this solution is good and could me marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first iteration should replace each 'a' with 'b'.
So,

```
'aba' -> 'bbb'
```

Second iteration should replace each b with 'ab'.
So,

```
'aba' -> 'bbb' -> 'ababab'.
```

That's precisely what your code is doing.

```
>>> SRS = { 'a':'b', 'b':'ab'}
>>> script = "aba"
>>> for key in SRS:
...     script = script.replace(key,SRS[key])
...     print(script)
...
bbb
ababab
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your first iteration in the loop is using changing 'a' to 'b', so you would have

```
aba = bbb
```

Then the second one changes b to ab, so you get

```
bbb = ababab
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this:

```
SRS = { 'a':'b', 'b':'ab'}
script = "aba"
```

After all "a" is replaced with "b",
then the value of `script` will be "bbb",
and after all "b" are replaced with "ab",
you get "ababab".

This is because you perform the replacements *in sequence*,
one after the other, one by one.

If you want to perform multiple replacements all at the same time,
you need to take a different approach.
You can use the `re` library's `sub` method.

```
import re

SRS = {'a': 'b', 'b': 'ab'}
p = re.compile('|'.join(SRS.keys()))

script = 'aba'
print(p.sub(lambda x: SRS[x.group(0)], script))
# prints: babb
```